# General solution of $x^{\prime}(t)=A x(t)$ [repeated real/complex eigenvalues case]

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-exponential

Could anybody give me the general solution of autonomous linear systems $X^{\prime}(t)=A X(t)$ in the case where there are repeated real eigenvalues and some complex repeated complex eigenvalues?

The case where they are all distinct is done by the following theorem but in the case where the eigenvalues are repeated, I didn't find something that could make me satisfied.

**Theorem:** Consider the system $X^{\prime}=A X$ where $A$ has distinct eigenvalues
$\lambda_{1}, \ldots, \lambda_{k_{1}} \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\alpha_{1}+i \beta_{1}, \ldots, \alpha_{k_{2}}+i \beta_{k_{2}} \in \mathbb{C} .$ Let $T$ be the matrix that puts
A in the canonical form
$T^{-1} A T=\left(\begin{array}{cccccc}{\lambda_{1}} \\ {} & {\ddots} & {} \\ {} & {} & {\lambda_{k_{1}}} & {} \\ {} & {} & {} & {B_{1}} \\ {} & {} & {} & {} & {\ddots} \\ {} & {} & {} & {} & {} & {B_{k_{2}}}\end{array}\right)$

where
$$
B_{j}=\left(\begin{array}{cc}{\alpha_{j}} & {\beta_{j}} \\ {-\beta_{j}} & {\alpha_{j}}\end{array}\right)
$$
Then the general solution of $X^{\prime}=A X$ is TY (t) where

$Y(t)=\left(\begin{array}{c}{c_{1} e^{\lambda_{1} t}} \\ {\vdots} \\ {\vdots} \\ {a_{1} e^{\alpha_{1} t} \cos \beta_{1} t+b_{1} e^{\alpha_{1} t} \sin \beta_{1} t} \\ {-a_{1} e^{\alpha_{1} t} \sin \beta_{1} t+b_{1} e^{\alpha_{1} t} \cos \beta_{1} t} \\ {\vdots} \\ {a_{k_{2}} e^{\alpha_{k_{2}} t} \cos \beta_{k_{2}} t+b_{k_{2}} e^{\alpha_{k_{2}} t} \sin \beta_{k_{2}} t} \\ {-a_{k_{2}} e^{\alpha_{k_{2}} t} \sin \beta_{k_{2}} t+b_{k_{2}} e^{\alpha_{k_{2}} t} \cos \beta_{k_{2}} t}\end{array}\right)$

Thanks for your help

Comment: The general solution depends on the Jordan form of the blocks associated with the repeated eigenvalues.

Comment: [Sorry I removed my last post because it was just a class question on Jordanisation] 
In my opinion, it should be a general formula depending on the parameters of the Jordan blog dimension. It just I couldn't found it yet.

Comment: So, is your question still active?

Comment: Yes, it's still active. if there are some defective real/complex eigenvalues of a real matrix A , what will be the general solution form of $X^{\prime}(t)=A X(t)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For general square matrix A there is Jordan form J so that

$A = PJP^{-1}$

Note that

$A^n = PJP^{-1}PJP^{-1}.....PJP^{-1} = PJ^nP^{-1}$

Therefore, following from Taylor series expansion (which containes different powers of A):

$e^{At} = Pe^{Jt}P^{-1}$.

Now in general

$J = \begin{bmatrix} J_1 && 0 && \cdots && 0 \\ 0 && J_2 && \cdots && 0 \\ \vdots && \vdots && \ddots && \vdots \\ 0 && 0 && \cdots && J_N\end{bmatrix} $

and

$J^n = \begin{bmatrix} J_1^n && 0 && \cdots && 0 \\ 0 && J_2^n && \cdots && 0 \\ \vdots && \vdots && \ddots && \vdots \\ 0 && 0 && \cdots && J_N^n\end{bmatrix} $

Therefore, again following from Taylor series expansion:

$e^{Jt} = \begin{bmatrix} e^{J_1t} && 0 && \cdots && 0 \\ 0 && e^{J_2t} && \cdots && 0 \\ \vdots && \vdots && \ddots && \vdots \\ 0 && 0 && \cdots && e^{J_Nt}\end{bmatrix} $

So if we can find expression for $e^{J_at}$ we are done as:

$e^{At} = Pe^{Jt}P^{-1} = P\begin{bmatrix} e^{J_1t} && 0 && \cdots && 0 \\ 0 && e^{J_2t} && \cdots && 0 \\ \vdots && \vdots && \ddots && \vdots \\ 0 && 0 && \cdots && e^{J_Nt}\end{bmatrix} P^{-1}$.

To find expression for $e^{J_at}$ we open up $e^{xt}$ as Taylor series expansion around the corresponding eigenvalue $\lambda_a$:

$e^{xt} = \sum \frac{t^ne^{\lambda_at}}{n!}(x-\lambda_a)^n$

and plug in $J_a$ in the expression

$e^{J_at} = \sum \frac{t^ne^{\lambda_at}}{n!}(J_a-\lambda_aI)^n$.

Here $(J_a-\lambda_aI)$ is a nilpotent matrix, only one above the main diagonal entries are one:

$J_a-\lambda_aI = \begin{bmatrix} 0 && 1 && 0 && \cdots && 0 \\ 0 && 0 && 1 && \cdots && 0 \\ \vdots && \vdots && \ddots && \ddots && \vdots\\ 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 1 \\ 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 \end{bmatrix}$

$(J_a-\lambda_aI)^2 = \begin{bmatrix} 0 && 0 && 1 && \cdots && 0 \\ 0 && 0 && 0 && \cdots && 0 \\ \vdots && \vdots && \ddots && \ddots && \vdots\\ 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 1 \\ 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 \\ 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 \end{bmatrix}$

$(J_a-\lambda_aI)^{m-1} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 && 0 && 0 && \cdots && 1 \\ 0 && 0 && 0 && \cdots && 0 \\ \vdots && \vdots && \ddots && \ddots && \vdots\\ 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 \\ 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 \\ 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 \end{bmatrix}$

where m is the dimension of the corresponding Jordan block $J_a$, and obviously $(J_a-\lambda_aI)^m$ and all the higher powers are zero. So we have just m terms in the taylor series which are nonzero and noting that the powers of $(J_a-\lambda_aI)$ follow a very nice pattern (ones shifts up at each power and eventually vanishes at power m), we have:

$e^{J_at} = \sum \frac{t^ne^{\lambda_at}}{n!}(J_a-\lambda_aI)^n = \begin{bmatrix} e^{\lambda_at} && te^{\lambda_at} && \frac{t^2}{2}e^{\lambda_at} && \cdots && \frac{t^{(m-1)}}{(m-1)!}e^{\lambda_at} \\ 0 && e^{\lambda_at} && te^{\lambda_at} && \cdots && \vdots \\ \vdots && \vdots && \ddots && \ddots && \vdots\\ 0 && 0 && 0 && e^{\lambda_at} && te^{\lambda_at} \\ 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && e^{\lambda_at} \end{bmatrix}$.

- EDIT:

This may not be very useful if you want to put it into real form with sines and cosines. There is another approach which I think is more useful for that purpose.

For initial condition response of the system to $x_0$ you can write $x_0$ as a linear combination of normal and generalized eigenvectors of A as they span whole $R^n$.

$x_0 = P \begin{bmatrix} c_1 \\ c_2 \\ \vdots \\ c_n\end{bmatrix}$

Then, you can write your solution as superposition of these individual responses. These base vectors are actually the columns of your P matrix for putting A into Jordan canonical form. Then for individual responses to these components, if it is a normal eigenvector you have:

$e^{At}(c_iv_i) = e^{\lambda_it}(c_iv_i)$.

For generalized eigenvectors you have:

$ e^{At}c_if_i = e^{\lambda_i}e^{(A-\lambda_iI)t}c_if_i= c_ie^{\lambda_it}\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}\frac{{t^k(A-\lambda_iI)^k}}{k!}f_i $

If $f_i$ is $r^{th}$ order generalized eigenvector, then all the powers starting from $r$ is zero and we have

$ e^{At}c_if_i = c_ie^{\lambda_it}\sum_{k = 0}^{r-1}\frac{{t^k(A-\lambda_iI)^k}}{k!}f_i = c_ie^{\lambda_it}\sum_{k = 0}^{r-1}\frac{{t^k}}{k!}f_i^{r-k} $

where $f_i^{r-k}$ denotes the $(r-k)^{th}$ order generalized eigenvector in the corresponding chain (as when you multiply your generalized eigenvector with $(A-\lambda_iI)$ each time its order decreases by one until you get normal eigenvector and higher powers are zero). However, if your eigenvector chains for certain eigenvalue are complex you must have also conjugate vectors for the correspondong conjugate eigenvalue and hence your coefficients will also be complex conjugate pairs for writing your $x_0$ as linear combination of eigenvectors. Therefore you have for conjugate pair of eigenvectors conjugate solutions:

$ e^{At}c_i^*f_i^* = c_i^*e^{\lambda_i^*t}\sum_{k = 0}^{r-1}\frac{{t^k(A-\lambda_i^*I)^k}}{k!}f_i^* = c_i^*e^{\lambda_i^*t}\sum_{k = 0}^{r-1}\frac{{t^k}}{k!}(f_i^{r-k})^* $

Note that for complex eigenvalues and eigenvectors corresponding coefficients $c_i$'s in the linear combination are also complex. From this point you may do simplifications and get to the sine/cosine representation of the system response.

Comment: Thank you Pasha for your clear reply. I suppose that the general solution has this form (in the case where $A \in \mathbb{M}_{n}(\mathbb{C})$: 

$$x(t)=\sum_{1 \leq i \leq N} e^{t \lambda_{i}}\left(\sum_{0 \leq k \leq m_{i}-1}  \frac{t^{k}}{k !} ({J}_{i}-\lambda_{i}I)^{k} x_{0}^{i}\right)$$  whith $$x(0)=x_{0}^{1}+\cdots+x_{0}^{N}$$

I think it's a little bit hard to deduce the general solution in the case where $A \in \mathbb{M}_{n}(\mathbb{R})$ from the previous one. Has anyone an idea about that?

Comment: I wrote how to compute $e^{At}$ and the solution is $e^{At}x_0$. Do you mean when A is complex matrix?

Comment: I read somewhere that it is "impolite" to write the solutions of an autonomous ode with $A \in \mathbb{M}_{n}(\mathbb{R})$ by a complex expression, therefore the general solution is expressed by cos and sin function. Still, I have no idea how to deduce this formula.
Another thing is I need to understand the general solution of Ode because it's usually used when they solve a Pde (variational formulation method), a parabolic for example.

Comment: Ok, now I understand what you mean. Don't you think it would be better to ask it as a seperate question?

Comment: ok, I'll try to write a new question with more precision. Thank you for your help

Comment: I entered new edit below the answer which I think is useful for your purpose.

Comment: I think that $x_{0}$ in the new base is $x_0 = P^{-1}\begin{bmatrix} c_1 \\ c_2 \\ \vdots \\ c_n\end{bmatrix}$ anc not $x_0 = P \begin{bmatrix} c_1 \\ c_2 \\ \vdots \\ c_n\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: Columns of matrix P are the eigenvectors of the matrix. Therefore if you want to get linear combination of its columns, you need to multiply it with c vector.

Comment: Could you take look at the [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basis_(linear_algebra)#Change_of_basis) .They said: **{** Let $A$ be the matrix of the $a_{i, j},$ and
$\
X=\left(\begin{array}{c}
{x_{1}} \\
{\vdots} \\
{x_{n}}
\end{array}\right) $ and$ Y=\left(\begin{array}{c}
{y_{1}} \\
{\vdots} \\
{y_{n}}
\end{array}\right)\]$


be the column vectors of the coordinates of $v$ in the old and the new basis respectively, then the formula for changing coordinates is
$X=AY$ . **}** so I still 'think' that $Y=A^{-1}X$ because A play the role of our P

Comment: These are different. Here just Assume that our $P$ is $A^{-1}$.

Comment: We define our $c$ vector such that: $x_0 = Pc$. There is no argument here.

Comment: We just try to write $x_0$ as a linear combination of columns of $P$, and define it this way. If you write $P^{-1}c$, then it is meaningless, because columns of $P^{-1}$ are not eigenvectors.

Comment: And this is just a matter of definition and up to us how we define $c$.

Comment: sorry I was confused 'again ;)', first $x_0$ is expressed in the canonical base, and we need its expression in the new base of generalized eigenVectors :D, which is the vector c, and since $x_0 = Pc$, we can conclude that $c = P^{-1}x_0$ , after getting the result, we use it in the general solution form. I hope I'm right now !!

Comment: Yes. Exactly : )

Answer (score 0):

Thank you again for your interisting addition, from my part I found the following result:

if $A \in \mathbb{M}_{n}(\mathbb{R})$ the solutions of $x^{\prime}(t)=A x(t)$ in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$
has the form:
$$
x(t)=\sum_{1 \leq j \leq q} e^{t \alpha_{j}}\left(\sum_{0 \leq k \leq m_{j}-1} t^{k}\left(\cos \left(\beta_{j} t\right) a_{j, k}+\sin \left(\beta_{j} t\right) b_{j, k}\right)\right)
$$
Where $\alpha_{j}=\operatorname{\Re}\left(\lambda_{j}\right), \beta_{j}=\Im m\left(\lambda_{j}\right)$ and the vectors $a_{j, k}, b_{j, k}$ are in $E_{j}$ (caracteristic space $\mathbb{R}^{n}=E_{1} \oplus \cdots \oplus E_{q}$)